# Buttons are not showing

Tags: css, windows-mobile, browser, windows-mobile-6.5, ie-mobile

I have this button tag:

```
<button data-bind="click: approve, text: Approve" type="button" id="approve" class="button">Approve</button>
```

One of my customers reported that, they can see only a plain text instead of buttons.

They are using [THIS](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_es400-3409.php) mobile phone/ barcode reader which comes with `Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional` I know that its already too old, but they need to be able to see correct my application on it.

The CSS I'm using is:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

.formElement { height: 30px; float: left; height: auto; margin: 0 0.4em; padding: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em; }
.formElement label { width: 17.89em; margin: 0.8em 0 0.1em 0.15em; font-size: 1.7em; display: block; }
.formElement textarea { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px; font-size: 1.15em; }
.formElement span { font-size: 1.05em; font-weight: bold; }
.lines { overflow: hidden; }
#commentInformation .formElement { width: 80%; }
input[type="text"] { float: left; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 0.2em; height: 1.6em; width: 29.4em; }
fileSelection { width: 50em; height: 30px; }
td
{
    background: #A9D0F5;
    text-align: center;
    height:2em;
}
th
{
    height:2em;
}
table
{
    width: 98%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    clear: both;
}
.customfile-button { color: #fff; float: right; width: 1px; padding: .3em .6em;  text-align: center; text-decoration: none;  font-size: 1.2em;  }
.fakeBrowseButton {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}  
input, select, textarea, button { font-family: inherit; }
.button, .regularButton { border: none; }
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm not able to spot it, because I never had to write something for `windows mobile 6.5.3` browser

Comment: Does the browser on the device show any button when surfing other web sites? Possibly they setup there device incorrectly. And, do not say WM653 is too old, it is still the most used OS for industrial used ruggedized devices. Windows Phone is more or less useless for such devices and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All phones render button elements differently.  If I was you I'd put in a media query that forces her resolution to display the button with border and a background so she can see it.

EDIT: Just read up on it and WAP (the browser she uses) does not support media queries. You could always just force styles onto the button site wide.

Answer (score 2):

In the .css file as shown in above box

```
.button, .regularButton { border: none; }
```

change it with

```
.button, .regularButton { border: 1px black solid; }
```

It will be show the button. Happy to help again!